# Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.com/pacote

Tags: node.js, npm, nativescript

I cant install nativescript-cli with npm when I run `npm install nativescript -g`. I dont know what is the reason.
node --version => 12.16.2
npm --version => 6.14.4

I tried :
-delete cache folder and `npm cache clean --force`
-`npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.com`
-turn off anti malware

but the issue is still unresolved.

here is npm log file output

```
11148 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Mohammad Reza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-57d686a6\test\function\invoke.js'
11149 warn tar ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Mohammad Reza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging\es5-ext-57d686a6\function\is-arguments.js'
11150 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/@sinonjs/commons/-/commons-1.6.0.tgz 22ms (from cache)
11151 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\Mohammad Reza\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-60ffea16dce7f1cb.lock for C:\Users\Mohammad Reza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\.staging
11152 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 2ms
11153 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 200098ms
11154 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: @types/node@8.10.30 (node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\@types\node):
11155 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.com/@types%2fnode (over 30000ms)
11156 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: typescript@3.3.4000 (node_modules\nativescript\node_modules\typescript):
11157 warn optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.com/typescript (over 30000ms)
11158 verbose type body-timeout
11159 verbose stack FetchError: Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.com/pacote (over 30000ms)
11159 verbose stack     at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\Users\Mohammad Reza\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:189:16)
11159 verbose stack     at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
11159 verbose stack     at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7)
11160 verbose cwd C:\Windows\system32
11161 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.18363
11162 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\Mohammad Reza\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "nativescript" "-g"
11163 verbose node v12.16.2
11164 verbose npm  v6.14.4
11165 error Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.com/pacote (over 30000ms)
11166 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Presumably you've already tried setting the registry to `https` instead of `http`, i.e. running `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/` ? Or similarly running `npm config delete registry` to set it back to the default registry, i.e. `https://registry.npmjs.org/` ?

Comment: Yes, I have tested both but I got the same result @RobC

Comment: Possibly related to `pacote`'s [issue #38](https://github.com/npm/pacote/issues/38).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was facing same issue, it seems to be a problem with `npm` versions `6.14.*`. Downgrading to `npm@6.13.1` worked for me.

```
npm i npm@6.13.1 -g
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue and I tried all the answers on Stackoverflow but not worked for me, finally I found solution for this issue:

- First of all you have to uninstall nodejs and remove all the files related him
- Go to "Register Editor" and search for all "nodejs", "node.js" and delete them
- Restart your computer
- And reinstall nodejs then install angular.

it's worked for me,
good luck :)